# Is it a normal process if all results by the "Track Change" function in MS-Word of my revised manuscript, are visible after being built in Elsevier?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, editors

I got a revision reply and the editor wanted me to use "**track change**" in Word to do changes in manuscript. I completed the revision for manuscript and responses to reviewers file. I re-submitted and got a PDF file (built through Elsevier system).

My revised manuscript showed full red lines and a disorder of lines and between revised figures and original figures. I am sure that the reviewers will be unable to see my revised part and get mad at me immediately.

If i do submit my Word revised manuscript which did **accept all changes** i implemented in manuscript.My revised manuscript is presented as final document. It will be good for reviewers to have a look on my revised paper. But how come the editor can see changes and modification in my manuscript?

If anyone coped with this process, please give me some advices and suggestion to **built a correct PDF file** based on Elsevier establishment.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

I think the comments and changes should have been accepted and then sent to the reviewers for them to appraise as necessary.

Comment: i think the same way